# infinite scroll without database

Tags: php, html, parsing, pagination, infinite-scroll

I'd like to know if it's possible to make an infinite scroll without a database.

I have a lot of data being parsed from different websites, so it's basically a list of links to news articles.  They're being updated on my page as they get inserted to the other sites.  I guess one way to do this is to have a cron job running every minute, 5 minutes, and inserting them into my database and then outputting it on my page.  Then I can make an infinite scroll.  But I wanted to know if it was possible to do without a database.

Maybe something like, on page load count how many article links there are and display only a certain amount?  I haven't been able to find any good examples for this.  Is it possible?

Comment: if you dont use a database, youre going to have to load the entire list everytime, with the database you just need to update it and show the changes

Comment: "Infinite scroll" is "pagination" is a sexier packaging. The only thing you need for pagination is to be able to break your data into chunks and selectively get *item "1-10", item "11-20"* etc. This requires no database in and of itself.

Comment: This is the most ridiculous questions I have seen in a long time. -1 for that (or +1 for humour)?

Comment: @EdHeal Seriously? It's not a great question, but it's not terrible either.

Comment: wow some people are mean on here.  I'm not a coding expert but I'm researching and learning.  Must be nice to sit up high on a pedestal and smite others.  Anyway, I know how it works with a database so I think I'll just do it that way.  Thanks for the advice who cared to give it!

Comment: @deceze - You have your opinion and I have mine. Your solution is not an infinite scroll. You just download a window into the database (could be a file) of X number of messages. Not infinite.

Comment: I think you are confusing 2 things: 1. periodically getting new content (you can use a javascript timeout instead of cron for that) and adding that to your page and 2. using pagination / infinite scroll. What exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: @EdHeal Uhm, let's suppose I have an infinite number of stuff? What's colloquially called "infinite scrolls" isn't typically *actually* infinite. Maybe you don't understand the usage of the term "infinite scroll"?

Comment: @EdHeal just because he mispelled or used a wrong term doesnt mean its a bad question at all, it just dont fit here. There is no need to be rude, everyone here is growup(i wish)

Comment: search the words Ajax and settimeinterval, both for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- Save data (in a file, in mysql...)
- Grab the data every time a user loads the page (check every page for news)

Of course it is better to save the data in some way, but it is possible to do it without a database or similar.

You have to realize that PHP starts from scratch every time the page is loaded, so you need something to store the information so that your PHP file doesn't have to repeat a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks @TheBronx, I'll stick to what I know and go with a database and sort by date to display the newest articles.  I'll make a cron job to check new articles every so often.